# What is a better way to write this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following relations.

```
Suppliers( sid: integer, sname: string, address: string)
Parts(pid: integer, pname: string, color: string)
Catalog( sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)
```

The problem asks me to find the pnames of parts supplied by Acme Widget Suppliers and no one else. I wrote the following SQL statement; however I feel like this query is inefficient because of the repetition. I would like to know if there is a better way to write this query without repeating the selecting catalog part.

```
Select P.pname 
FROM Parts P 
WHERE P.pid IN (
    Select C.pid 
    FROM Catalog C 
    INNER JOIN Supplier S
    ON S.sid = C.sid 
    WHERE S.sname = "Acme Widget Suppliers" 
    AND C.pid NOT IN (
            SELECT C2.pid 
            FROM Catalog C2
            INNER JOIN Supplier S
            ON S.sid = C2.sid 
            WHERE S.sname <> "Acme Widget Suppliers"
        )
);
```

Comment: Please clarify by what you mean when you say `"by Acme Widget Suppliers and no one else."`  Do you mean you want _only_ Acme parts, or do you want parts by Acme _and_ parts made by no one?

Comment: the question is ambiguous at best. pid 1 and 7 can both have the same name, like Cracker Jacks. But the pid is in the junction table

Comment: it means that we need to find the parts supplied only by Acme Widget Suppliers. If the part is supplied by Acme and another supplier, then it doesn't count.

Comment: by part name or pid. Work with us here. The devil's in the details, and it is rearing its spikey horns

Comment: by part name just as the question stated. I didn't actually write this question. This is a homework question and I just want to learn a more elegant way to solve this problem

Comment: that is not what the question stated. If the nuance is too difficult to grasp, I be moving on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work:

```
select p.pname from Catalog c
join Parts p on p.pid = c.pid
join Suppliers s on s.sid = c.sid
where s.sname = 'Acme Widget Suppliers'
and p.pid in (select pid as SupplierCount from Catalog c
              group by pid having count(*) = 1)
```

The inner `select` is meant to find exclusive parts from *any* supplier. If a part is sold by multiple providers, it will not be included.

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ccde/10

Comment: Good use of count here. This solution is very easy to understand :)

Comment: Thansks! I used TSQL by accident (I read MSSQL instead of MySQL). I checked based on another fiddle and it still works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/895a49/9

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The query you want to make can be greatly simplified. Try the following.

```
SELECT P.pname FROM Parts P, Suppliers S, Catalog C
WHERE C.pid = P.pid
AND C.sid = S.sid
AND S.sname == "Acme Widget Suppliers"
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `left join` on the second part because I expect get `nulls`. In that case only one row for acme and no one else

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae789/6)**

```
Select *
FROM Parts P 
INNER JOIN Catalog C1
   ON P.pid = C1.pid
INNER JOIN Suppliers S1
   ON C1.sid = S1.sid
LEFT JOIN Catalog C2
   ON P.pid = C2.pid
  AND C1.sid <> C2.sid
WHERE 
   S1.sname = 'Acme' 
AND C2.sid IS NULL
```

Comment: I make a fiddle and improve my query. Including the second join the `<> C1.sid` i make sure i join some other company. And if that join Is null You got it. Check the demo removing the last line `and c2.sid is null` and you will see all results.

Answer (score 2):

The correct query would be:

```
Select P.PName from Suppliers S1 
 join Catalog C1
  on S1.sid = C1.sid
  join parts P
   on P.pid = C1.pid
where  S1.sname = 'Acme Widget Suppliers'
 and not exists 
 ( select  1 from catalog C2 where C2.sid != C1.sid 
   and C2.pid = C1.pid)
```

The not exist is very efficient as it stops to search when it finds the first occurence.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/895a49/6/0)

Answer (score 1):

I would just try joining together the three tables, then restricting with the `WHERE` clause you already were using.  I used `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` statement to ensure that duplicates get taken out, should they occur.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pname
FROM  Parts p INNER JOIN Catalog c
ON p.pid = c.pid
INNER JOIN Suppliers s
ON c.sid = s.sid
WHERE s.sname = "Acme Widget Suppliers"
```

Comment: The question says "supplied by Acme Widget Suppliers and no one else" - you don't have the "no one else" part.

Comment: I interpreted the `"no one else"` phrase to be redundant, i.e. `"supplied by ONLY Acme Widget Suppliers"`.  I am wrong here?

Comment: Yes. Car A is sell by Ford and Chevrolet. Car B is sell only by Dodge. An you can get that interpretion from OP query

Comment: @Kobi: You dont need a no one else part because you only selct the items from Acme Widget. If you add a statement like and s.name <> 'Acme Widget' it's like saying geting all even numbers which are not odd.

Comment: @TobiSH - Please read  Juan's comment that explains that beautifully. We are looking for parts sold **exclusively** by Acme.

Answer (score 1):

To provide another way to tackle this one here a variant using grouping of data. It is a solution to select all **pnames** that were provided by and only by 'Acme Widget Suppliers'

```
Select P.pname 
FROM Parts P 
INNER JOIN Catalog C on c.pid=p.pid
INNER JOIN Supplier S  ON S.sid = C.sid 
GROUP BY p.pname 
HAVING min(s.sname)=max(s.sname) 
   and max(s.name)='Acme Widget Suppliers'
```

The select groups by pname and calculates the **min** and **max** of suppliers name. If there are different suppliers of one part **min** and **max** are not equal.

As I understand the nuance within the question (Part provided by 'Acme' or Part provided by 'Acme' and no one else) is still not clear, I will stick to the later and more difficult selection ;).

Comment: another brilliant solution :)  I would never thought about this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per your query, seems to be not in not required also `exists` statement is much better than `in` and join.

```
Select P.pname 
FROM Parts P 
WHERE EXISTS (
    Select C.pid 
    FROM Catalog C 
    INNER JOIN Supplier S
    ON S.sid = C.sid 
    WHERE P.pid = C.pid  AND  S.sname = "Acme Widget Suppliers" 
);
```

Comment: Better than `IN` I agree, But what is your source to say `EXISTS`  are better than `JOIN`?